# Makefile: Why can't I see compilation output?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, automake

I have a master `Makefile` that calls submakefiles inside directories.
Those submakefiles are generated by autotools starting from `Makefile.am` and `configure.ac` files.

The first target of the entire project is a shared library, while the others are executables that link against it (so there is a dependency in the main `Makefile`).

The problem is that I can only see the compilation output of the shared library, while the other projects are just printing warnings and errors (just `stderr` text, I believe).

I can't understand what is causing this behaviour since all the projects are called from the very same rule in the master `Makefile` and all the submakefiles are autogenerated from very seemed configuration files.

The snippet of master `Makefile` that compiles all the targets looks like this:

```
SUBDIRS = libMylib app1 app2 app3

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(ECHO) "-> Building $@"
    $(MAKE) -C $@
    $(ECHO) "-> Build of $@ finished."
```

The output of "libMylib" is like:

```
-> Building libMylib
libtool: compile:  ppc-linux-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/opt/ELDK/ppc_8xx/usr/include/ -I/opt/ELDK/ppc_8xx/include/ -Wall -std=gnu99 -O2 -MT libMylibF1.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libMylibF1.Tpo -c libMylibF1.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libMylibF1.o
...
libtool: link: ppc-linux-gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/libMylibF1.o .libs/libMylibF2.o .libs/libMylibF3.o -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/ELDK/ppc_8xx/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/ELDK/ppc_8xx/lib -lz -lpthread  -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libMylib.so.0 -o .libs/libMylib.so.0.0.0
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libMylib.so.0" && ln -s "libMylib.so.0.0.0" "libawmg.so.0")
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libMylib.so" && ln -s "libMylib.so.0.0.0" "libMylib.so")
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libMylib.la" && ln -s "../libMylib.la" "libMylib.la" )
-> Build of libAwmg finished.
```

While the output of any "appN" is:

```
-> Building app1
app1F1.c: In function `app1F1Func1':
app1F1.c:161: warning: unused variable `varA'
app1F2.c:85: warning: `app1F2FuncX' defined but not used
-> Build of app1 finished.
```

Could anyone please help me?

---

EDIT:

I found out that I was able to see the compile stuff in "libMylib" because it is "libtoolized".
If I "libtoolize" another project, I can see the linker part of the output (`libtool: link:...`).

So, considering that `make` calls a shell (`sh`) for each line in the rule, that $(MAKE) equals to just "make" and, by default, `make` is verbose, why do the submake is not printing its output to stdout?

Which flags may be passed to it so that this happens?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the Makefiles in the sub directories.  If, for example, you have a @ in front of the compile commands in the app Makefiles, then they will not output the commands that were being run (also look for $(Q), which is used quite commonly when you want to enable/disable verboseness in makefiles).  Alternatively, your make commands in the apps directories may be pushing stdout to some files (which would still allow you to see the warnings).

By the same token your library makefile may be incorrectly redirecting stderr elsewhere, which would explain why you don't see any error outputs on that (or it just doens't have any errors...)

Please post the build rules in the other directories (and all associated variable definitions) if you want more help.

Comment: The submakefiles are generated by autoconf/automake, so they are a bit verbose (and that's why I haven't posted it). If I run any of it directly in a terminal, I see the output as expected. The thing only happen when called from the main Makefile. Please see my edit above...

Answer (score 1):

Well, my master makefile includes another file that puts a `.SILENT` rule in.

I haven't noticed that until today.
Removing this rule makes everithing work as expected.

Oh my...